# vmap automatically puts '<,'> infront of excommands

Tags: vim

I'm trying to write a copy/paste function for visual mode vim. Copy reads all the lines highlighted.

`vmap cc :execute Copy()<CR>`

turns into

`'<,'>:execute Copy()<CR>`

which results in 

`E481: No range allowed`

How can I get vmap not to insert '<,'> when going into ex mode?

Comment: I'm curious: what does your `Copy()` function do that's not already covered by `y`?

Comment: Usually have multiple tmux sessions with multiple instances of vim. Use Copy() when copying text between different vim instances.

Comment: Hmm. what about `"+y` and `"+p`?

Comment: I wish. I use vim in tmux which loses access to the clipboard on a mac because of namespace [issues](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard)

Comment: Only if you don't implement the fix available on that page. I have that line in my `.tmux.conf` without any issue.

Comment: I sync dotfiles between multiple machines and didn't want to have a mac specific option in my `.tmux.conf` that had a dependency on another binary. also used it as an excuse to use vimscript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use <kbd>C-u</kbd> to clear command line.

```
vmap cc :<C-u>execute Copy()<CR>
```